# Sqlite Select Query with where clause in python return none

Tags: python, sqlite

My sqlite select query with where clause in python return none or empty (>>> )

```
import os.path
import sqlite3

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "Dictionary.db")
with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as db:
    t = ('hello',)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM entries Where word=?",t)
    Value = cursor.fetchall()
    for i in Value:
        print (i)
```

Output:
        ( >>> )

But when I use simple select query without where clause it returns all data

Comment: Please paste the `INSERT`s, so that people can reproduce the behavior. Also, maybe you're just missing quotes around the word i.e.: `SELECT * FROM entries Where word="?"`.

Comment: This is mentioned in sqlite official website

Comment: are you sure you have a row with `word = 'hello'` ?

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT word='hello', * FROM entries`? Does one row get marked with `1`?

Comment: Yes I have because this is db of dictionary containing 176023 words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

`cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM entries Where word=?",(t,))`

The second argument should be a tuple or a list.